# How to use a form to send values to JS file and execute NodeJS

Tags: node.js, forms, express

I'm starting in NodeJS and to practice I'm creating a project where I have a form with some fields, the form is created inside the *views* folder as *teste.ejs.*

**Teste.ejs**

```
<div class="container">
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="/inndetails.js">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="fname">MerchantID</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="merchantid" placeholder="MerchantID..">
  </div>
<div class="row"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="fname">Valor</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="text" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="Valor..">
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

This form has two fields "MerchantID" and "Valor". I want when I submit using POST the values from these fields go to an JS file called "inndetails.js" and execute this file.

**Inndetails.js**

```
sdk.getIinDetails({
'psp_Version': '2.2',
'psp_MerchantId': '**From the form**',
'psp_IIN': '**From the form**',
'psp_PosDateTime': '2016-12-01 12:00:00'
},
function (error, response) {
if (error) {
    console.log(error)
} else {
    console.log(response);
}
});
```

I am already using Express and Body Parser, In my *routes* folder I have the file **index.js** contains:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/teste2', urlencodeParser, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
res.render('teste2', ´{data: req.body});
});
```

I can get the values from the form and show in another page for example in **teste2.ejs**, using:

```
<p>MerchantID: <%= data.merchantid %></p>
<p>Valor: <% data.valor %></p>
```

Comment: Firstly you need expressjs and bodyparser(for read requests).

Comment: Already using them, I edited the question with more details about it, I can get the values and show them in another page for example, I can handle the object called data, now only need to know how to send them to my js file called inndetails.js and execute

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your index.js file to

```js
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/teste2', bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: false }), function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
res.render('teste2', ´{data: req.body});
});
```

The parameters `{limit: '50mb', extended: false }` is an option, and you can see the others here https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser
`